# Open source browser based solution for Serilog or NLog

Tags: logging, nlog, serilog

Is there a open source web application option available for Serilog or NLog. I'm looking to host application on IIS, that can target file based logs. I found [TailBlazer](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/TailBlazer) that's open source but its Windows application that too doesn't search through entire folder but can only search in a file.

Comment: Is file based a must have? Most web based stuff uses databases or elastic etc.

Comment: @Julian - Doesn't need to be a file. But can't do DB. Are there any open source options then?

Comment: Needs is also to be free? (FOSS)

Comment: for personal or commercial software?  (or open source? ;) )

Comment: @Julian - Looking for open source options.

Comment: getseq.net and be done with it